Realizing auto-inputting command after logging in session in PuTTy
Is there an option in Putty that can auto-insert commands when I start a session?
The general scheme will look like this:
Start session -> Auto logging with a certificate -> Insert the command "ssh username@host" to connect to another SSH session.
That's very strange, but I really need this.
I will accept any suggestion and advice.

It's possible:
How to run a remote command in PuTTY after login & keep the shell running?

But PuTTY allows tunneling nativelly, no need to run a command for that. On the Connection > Proxy panel, select "SSH to proxy and use port forwarding" and specify details of the jump host. For details, see:
How to setup proxy jump with PuTTY
